# Quicksort - Space complexity - Why is it O(logN) not O(N)?

Tags: quicksort

So in quicksort, the space complexity is said to be O(log N) but here is what I've thought. Since the logN arises from the stack calls, one can always choose the worst pivot leading to O(N) calls rather than O(logN) calls? Shouldn't it be O(N)?

Comment: This can be found anywhere there is a description of the algorithm, such as [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Comment: @ken Should we answer it, then? Even if its trivial, I think its on-topic for the site.

Comment: here is an article that i came across, the wiki link does not provide full information https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-tail-call-optimization-reducing-worst-case-space-log-n/amp/

Comment: @JakobLovern: It doesn't show any research effort at all, as the reason for the complexity is discussed many times in many places, including the post I linked. You're free to answer it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

This java example limits stack space to O(log(n)) by only using recursion for the smaller part, then looping back to handle the larger part. Worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

```
public static void qsort(long[] a, int lo, int hi)
{
    while(lo < hi){
        int  md = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
        int  ll = lo-1;
        int  hh = hi+1;
        long p = a[md];
        long t;
        while(true){
            while(a[++ll] < p);
            while(a[--hh] > p);
            if(ll >= hh)
                break;
            t     = a[ll];
            a[ll] = a[hh];
            a[hh] = t;
        }
        ll = hh++;
        if((ll - lo) <= (hi - hh)){
            qsort(a, lo, ll);
            lo = hh;
        } else {
            qsort(a, hh, hi);
            hi = ll;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: too complicated to understand without paying "high" attention